# I want to combine two table to get result

Tags: mysql, join

i have two tables,

1.Orders,
2.Items.

1.Orders Skeleton

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2.Items Skeleton

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Records :

1.Orders Table with Data

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Order1 |
|  2 | Order2 |
|  3 | Order3 |
+----+--------+
```

2.Items Table with Data

```
+----+----------+---------+-------+
| id | order_id | name    | price |
+----+----------+---------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | Mobile1 | 25000 |
|  2 |        1 | Mobile2 | 30000 |
|  3 |        1 | Mobile3 |  6500 |
|  4 |        2 | Mobile4 | 10000 |
+----+----------+---------+-------+
```

I want to get items which are having same order_id,

```
 Select id[Orders], order_id[items], name[items]1, name[items]2, name[items]3...
```

Suggestions Pls...

Comment: You want each name as a column? or all names as one column separated by comma?

Comment: That's not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to do that because you're (or mysql) unaware of how many rows it will fetch during the execution of the query. You need to get all the data first and use any programming language to print them in any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you only need to access table `items` to get what you need.

```
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT( name SEPARATOR ', ') item_names
FROM items
GROUP BY order_id;
```

Comment: But also i want those records(name) with separate column...

But this gives data's in single column..

Comment: Then you will need other techniques to convert row to columns. U can search on StackOverflow and there are already solutions. But more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I get solution for only known number of fields....

Row to Column:

**STEP : 1**

```
select @orderID:=order_id, 
@name:=GROUP_CONCAT(name) item_names, 
@price:=GROUP_CONCAT(price) item_price 
from item group by order_id limit 1;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
+----------+-------------------------+------------------+
| order_id | item_names              | item_price       |
+----------+-------------------------+------------------+
|        1 | Mobile1,Mobile2,Mobile3 | 25000,30000,6500 |
+----------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

**STEP : 2**

```
select @orderID,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ',', 1),',',-1) as Name1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@price, ',', 1),',',-1) as Price1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ',', 2),',',-1) as Name2, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@price, ',', 2),',',-1) as Price2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ',', 3),',',-1) as Name3, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@price, ',', 3),',',-1) as Price3;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
| @orderID | Name1   | Price1 | Name2   | Price2 | Name3   | Price3 |
+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
|        1 | Mobile1 | 25000  | Mobile2 | 30000  | Mobile3 | 6500   |
+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
```